# Print all rows where the day of birth can be found in the phone number using awk

Tags: awk

in my assignment I have to create an awk script. The script should print all rows where the day of birth can be found in the phone number.

**Here are som row from the input file:**

```
firstname,lastname,city,born,phone,email

Salma,Helin,Hällaryd,2002-07-03,555674792,salma.helin@hallaryd.se

Sanna,Wahlgren,Torhamn,2004-08-02,555493393,sanna.wahlgren@torhamn.se

Anni,Örn,Resarö,1994-07-08,555408537,anni.orn@resaro.se

Thilda,Brandt,Holmsjö,1994-06-25,555197921,thilda.brandt@holmsjo.se

Teo,Stenström,Borgholm,1994-04-29,555229873,teo.stenstrom@borgholm.se

Alexis,Sjödin,Ardala,1991-03-04,555190611,alexis.sjodin@ardala.se

Stina,Örn,Gladö kvarn,2010-05-25,555622513,stina.orn@glado_kvarn.se
```

**The desired output is:**

```
Anni Örn, 1994-07-08, 555408537

Teo Stenström, 1994-04-29, 555229873

Stina Örn, 2010-05-25, 555622513
```

**Here how far I got**

```
BEGIN { FS="," }

NR == 1 { next }

{
    split($4, d, "-") 
    day = d[3]     
}
```

I tried split the date and extract the day of birth. Now I have to some how find match in field `5`. For example `08` exist in `555408537`. Now I am stuck. I don't know accomplish this assignment. I am open to any suggestion.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might use [`index`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) function, it gives start of match if found or 0 otherwise, so in your case is it enough to check `>0`. Let `file.txt` content be

```
firstname,lastname,city,born,phone,email
Salma,Helin,Hällaryd,2002-07-03,555674792,salma.helin@hallaryd.se
Sanna,Wahlgren,Torhamn,2004-08-02,555493393,sanna.wahlgren@torhamn.se
Anni,Örn,Resarö,1994-07-08,555408537,anni.orn@resaro.se
Thilda,Brandt,Holmsjö,1994-06-25,555197921,thilda.brandt@holmsjo.se
Teo,Stenström,Borgholm,1994-04-29,555229873,teo.stenstrom@borgholm.se
Alexis,Sjödin,Ardala,1991-03-04,555190611,alexis.sjodin@ardala.se
Stina,Örn,Gladö kvarn,2010-05-25,555622513,stina.orn@glado_kvarn.se
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=","}NR==1{next}{split($4, d, "-");day = d[3];if(index($5,day)>0){print}}' file.txt
```

output

```
Anni,Örn,Resarö,1994-07-08,555408537,anni.orn@resaro.se
Teo,Stenström,Borgholm,1994-04-29,555229873,teo.stenstrom@borgholm.se
Stina,Örn,Gladö kvarn,2010-05-25,555622513,stina.orn@glado_kvarn.se
```

Note that due to how `if` behaves you do not have to compare with 0 explicitly, but might do

```
BEGIN{FS=","}NR==1{next}{split($4, d, "-");day = d[3];if(index($5,day)){print}}
```

and get same result. I left reworking `print`-ing to show desired column as exercise. As side note: rather than skipping unwanted lines using `next` you might register action only for interesting lines, in this case

```
BEGIN{FS=","}NR>1{split($4, d, "-");day = d[3];if(index($5,day)){print}}
```

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*

Answer (score 1):

You can try this `awk` which will check if the day matches within the phone number.

```
awk -F"[,-]" '$7 ~ $6 && /./' input file
```

`$7 ~ $6` will check for a match in the two columns

`/./` will remove the blank lines

**Output**

```
Anni,Örn,Resarö,1994-07-08,555408537,anni.orn@resaro.se
Teo,Stenström,Borgholm,1994-04-29,555229873,teo.stenstrom@borgholm.se
Stina,Örn,Gladö kvarn,2010-05-25,555622513,stina.orn@glado_kvarn.se
```

Comment: If one of the names were a compound one like,  `Gun-Britt,Örn,Resarö,1994-07-08,...` this approach would fail to find it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another awk alternative:

```
$ awk -F, 'NR > 1 && $5 ~ substr($4,9,10)' input
Anni,Örn,Resarö,1994-07-08,555408537,anni.orn@resaro.se
Teo,Stenström,Borgholm,1994-04-29,555229873,teo.stenstrom@borgholm.se
Stina,Örn,Gladö kvarn,2010-05-25,555622513,stina.orn@glado_kvarn.se
```

**Explanation:** With the field separator set to comma-separated values, print all records apart from the first (the header) where field number 5 matches the last part of the date in field 4.